# terraform kubernetes provider: namespace destination

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm creating an ingress using terraform `kubernetes_ingress` resource:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "this" {
    metadata {
        name = "mongodb-ingress"
    }

    spec {
        backend {
            service_name = "mongodb"
            service_port = 9092
        }

        rule {
            http {
                path {
                    path = "/mongodb/*"
                    backend {
                        service_name = "mongodb"
                        service_port = 9092
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me which namespace will be assigned this ingress rule on.

I've tried to get if there's any `namespace` property, but I don't quite figure out where is it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't specify it and apply it does it not just end up in the default namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a namespace property in terraform kubernetes provider. Please take a loot at [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/ingress#namespace).

If you don't specify a namespace then it'll be created in default namespace.

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "this" {
    metadata {
        name = "mongodb-ingress"
        namespace = "dev"
    }

    spec {
        backend {
            service_name = "mongodb"
            service_port = 9092
        }

        rule {
            http {
                path {
                    path = "/mongodb/*"
                    backend {
                        service_name = "mongodb"
                        service_port = 9092
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

kubectl get ing -n dev
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
mongodb-ingress   <none>   *                 80      7s
```